# get query id on click in esp8266 arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

can someone kindly tell me how to get query id on click using the module chip and not wifishield? At this point, I just need someone to point me to the right direction (after days of searching), what do I need to send the clicked id to arduino?

site.com/query?id=123 // how do i get 123 on click? given that the id may change on click.

```
String getId= "GET /query?id=123 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: site.com:80\r\n\r\n";
```

currently I am able to send to web. Also I am able to get the data on the webpage but that's not what I want.

Comment: Please could you post your Arduino code so that we can see what you've tried? It will help us to identify the problem and suggest solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the id=xxx ( where XXX is the number you want to get ) , you could have a bit of split strings.

```
int equalPosition = getId.indexOf("id=");
int HTTPPosition = getId.indexOf("HTTP");

String id = getId.substring(equalPosition,HTTPPosition-1);
```